# Python/openpyxl get conditional format

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, openpyxl

I'm working on a Project with python and openpyxl.

In a Excel file are some cells with conditional formatting. These change the infillcolor, when the value changes. I need to extract the color from the cell.

The "normal" methode

`worksheet["F11"].fill.start_color.index`

doesn't work. Excel doesn't interpret the infillcolor from the conditional formatting as infillcolor so i get a `'00000000'` back for no infill.

Anyone knows how to get the infillcolor?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible without you writing some of your own code.

To do this you will have to write code that can evaluate conditional formatting because openpyxl is a library for the file format and not a replacement for an application like Excel.